# How to get the group generators from the coordinate transformation for field?

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'm reading Di Francesco' CFT recently and have some problems with how to find the generator of the conformal group. In (4.15) he showed the conformal transformations in $d\geq3$, and he use $\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$, and $\phi'(x)-\phi(x)=-i\omega_aG_a\phi(x)$ to get the generator $G_a$. I don't understand why this is valid, is it related to killing field or something?
Under a coordinate transformation $x\mapsto x'=gx$, where $g\in G$ a group element, the corresponding transformation for field should be $\phi'(x')=\pi(g)\phi(x)$, where $\pi$ is a group representation, then why here we just need the trivial representation $\pi(g)=id$ ?

Comment: In general $\phi'(x')=\pi(g)\phi(x)$, $\phi'(x)-\phi(x)=-i\omega_aG_a\phi(x)$, then $G_a$ is called the generator for the transformation, but if $\phi'(x')=\phi(x)$, it's also the generator for the group. Is it just a trick or there is some principle behind?

Comment: You should consider the action of a one parameter subgroup. Its infinitesimal action defines a vector field viewed as a differential operator. That is the "generator" the book refers to.